# Azure, Publish Bottle Web App using Visual Studios

Tags: python, visual-studio, azure

I'm attempting to do publish a pre-made bottle web app in Visual Studios called “Bottle Web Project”. I submit the project to “publish” go to the website and I get the default, "Hey, App Service developers! Your app service is up and running. Time to take the next step and deploy your code."

I used this instructional video found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJXDGaEPy94

I’ve tried almost everything I can think of:

- Changing port number
- Upload on GitHub and importing from Github
- Re-uploading using Azure Publish Settings
- Delete and reapply profile
- “Validate Connection” – Correct

About the project:

- I’m using local environment for Python
- The debugger runs fine (it’s a premade program)
- Configuration: “Release”
- Visual studios is creating a windows "App service plan" instead of a linux, that's 1 problem. In addition, the "App service" is using NET instead of Python. However, after these changes the app still won't publish

Does anyone know of a solution as to why I’m not getting the default homepage to be the same as what I’m seeing from other instructional videos and webpages?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the solution. Turns out almost all the resources are out-dated and there are slight (but significant) modifications you'll have to do.

Step 1:  [Publish to App Service - Visual Studio 2017 and later](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publish-to-app-service-windows?view=vs-2019#publish-to-app-service---visual-studio-2017-and-later)

Step 2: Follow the steps on the link with these slight modifications:

> 1. You cannot create a "Windows" web app using Python - it will automatically create a "Linux" web app (which is not what we wanted to
>      do)
> 2. To bypass (1) you let VS create the resources by creating new resource when you publish
> 3. In addition, you'll have to add the Python Extension. To do this, Azure resources, your web app -> Under "Development Tools" click
>      Extensions -> Add Python 3.6.4x64 (or whatever is recent)
> 4. When adding the correct paths to "Script Processor" the default is lowercase python. To get the path you can check by: Azure resources,
>      your web app -> Under "Development Tools" click Console. From the
>      console you can navigate to your python extension and get the paths
> 5. Once you go through steps 9 (a) - (f) [which i had to do all of them to get the app up and running] give the app a minute or two for
>      everything to work.

For the answer click here: [Azure Visual Studios Bottle Web-App Publish Not Working](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/77ba2bad-66fe-4881-926a-e659b7e8ed0a/azure-visual-studios-bottle-webapp-publish-not-working)

Comment: Quoting and citing source material is a critical step when referencing somebody's words.  I have resolved the grammatical and unquoted text in your answer.  In the future it would be entirely up to you to do that yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound They were my words both here and their. I posted this on 2 boards to get an answer.

Comment: That isn't immediately obvious you were the author to the post on the MS Forums.